# Performing the fastest search - which collection should i use?

Tags: java, search, collections, time-complexity

I know:

- If you need fast access to elements using index, ArrayList should be choice.
- If you need fast access to elements using a key, use HashMap.
- If you need fast add and removal of elements, use LinkedList (but it has a very poor seeking performance).

In order to perform the fastest search, on the basis of data stored in a collection object, which collection should I use?

Below is my code:

```
    public void fillAndSearch(Collection<Student> collection) {
      if(collection!=null){
        for (int i=0; i<=10; i++) {
            Student student = new Student("name" + i, "id" + i);
            collection.add(student);
        }
      }
        //here We have to perform searching for "name7" or "id5",
        //then which implementation of collection will be fastest?
    }

class Student {
    String name;
    String id;

    Student(String name, String id) {
        this.name = name;
        this.id = id;
    }
}
```

Comment: use ArrayList because it searching based on indexing

Comment: Is your data ALWAYS in the form of `collection.get(i) = [name_i, id_i]`? (with the same value of `i` for the index, the name, and the id)?

Comment: When searching, the fast access is primordial, so `HashMap` or `ArrayList` (think about sorted list and dichotomy). But in your case, I would instantiate a `HashMap<String, Student>`, and map the id and the name to the student, so you will find your student in O(1) (if there is no hash collision) !

Comment: Use `java.util.HashMap` to store the Objects and the use the Key i.e. name or id, two maps actually one with key as name other with key as id

Comment: @amit  collection.get(i) is always a object of student which is collection all about,I am not able reach U properly what U asking?

Comment: @amit no such restriction this is just dumy.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The thing which is often skipped when comparing `ArrayList` and `LinkedList` is cache and memory management optimisations. `ArrayList` is effectively just an array which means that it is stored in a continuous space in the memory. This allows the Operating System to use optimisations such as "when a byte in memory was accessed, most likely the next byte will be accessed soon". Because of this, `ArrayList` is faster than `LinkedList` in all but one case: when inserting/deleting the element at the beginning of the list (because all elements in the array have to be shifted). Adding/deleting at the end or in the middle, iterating over, accessing the element are all faster in case of `ArrayList`.

If you need to search for student with given name **and** id, it sounds to me like a map with composite key - `Map<Student, StudentData>`. I would recommend to use `HashMap` implementation, unless you need to be able to both search the collection and retrieve all elements sorted by key in which case `TreeMap` may be a better idea. Although remember that `HashMap` has `O(1)` access time, while `TreeMap` has `O(logn)` access time.

Comment: Will save and read this answer whenever I need to understand the difference between collections))

Answer (score 2):

With given restrictions, you should use HashMap.
It will give you quick search, as you wished.

If you care about traversing elements in specific order, you should choose TreeMap (natural order) or LinkedHashMap (insertion order).

If your collection is guaranteed immutable, you can use sorted ArrayList with binary search, it will save you some memory. In this case, you can search only by one specific key, which is undesirable in many real world applications.

Anyway, you should have really **huge** number of elements (millions/billions) to feel the difference between O(logN) solutions and O(1) solutions.

If you want to learn more about data structures, I recommend you to review Algorythms course by Princeton university on coursera.com

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong in keeping multiple collections to access your data faster.

In this situation I would use 2 `HashMap<String, Student>`'s. One for each search-key.

*(PS: Or if you don't know which kind of keyword is used to search for, then you can store both in the same map).*