# which is best collection ArrayList or LinkedList as always shifting position of it's all entry while removing first entry frequently?

Tags: java

I have to implement an algorithm that entry always inserted last and entry removed from first position.

i checked following link

[Performing the fastest search - which collection should i use?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30321169/performing-the-fastest-search-which-collection-should-i-use)

They say "ArrayList is stored in a continuous space in the memory. This allows the Operating System to use optimisations such as "when a byte in memory was accessed, most likely the next byte will be accessed soon". Because of this, ArrayList is faster than LinkedList in all"

but one case: when inserting/deleting the element at the beginning of the list (because all elements in the array have to be shifted). Adding/deleting at the end or in the middle, iterating over, accessing the element are all faster in case of ArrayList.

Here  In my algorithm,always remove first element .So,always shifting happens.In that case i should not use arraylist??

Comment: I’m thinking [`ArrayDeque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) will be the best choice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It really depend on what more you wish to do with the structure.

If most of the time you are just adding at the end and removing from the start then any implementation of [Deque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) would do. So [ArrayDeque](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html) or [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html) are probably your best candidates.

`ArrayDeque` is backed by an array and can therefore be accessed quickly by index with `O(1)` complexity but it has the downside that adding can be slower than `LinkedList` because sometimes the backing array needs to be resized.

`LinkedList` is just a linked-list so growing/shrinking it is consistently `O(1)` but accessing by index is not because to find the `nth` entry is `O(n)`.

Comment: Sadly, `ArraxDeque` can't be accesses by index :-(. They're exploring retrofitting it to `List`, too, but it's surprisingly complex: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143850. It's just a circular fifo buffer that tends to be faster than linked list if you do not grow it badly.

Comment: if i am going to use removeFirst(),size(),add() method only,can i choose LinkedList confidently mam??

Comment: @jagadeeshkalaiyarasan - Yes! Of those only `size` is not guaranteed to be `O(1)` but it usually is.